# Light not working

Tags: modeling, rendering, lighting, visibility

I have 132 spot lights in the scene but last 2 are not working, although the data is same. I added another area light and it's also not working, although the previous one were working. I've closed and opened the program and they worked but just after sometime they again stopped working. What is causing that? I need to adjust the intensity of light, but that's impossible when the effect of light cannot be seen.

Comment: there is a max number of lights you can use

Comment: If you're talking Eevee, see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html
In Cycles you should have no limit in theory until your hardware is maxed out.